# How can I specify the page of the field to merge info in a template in Adobe Sign API v6

Tags: javascript, node.js, adobe-sign

I have a template with read only text fields and I want to merge info using the endpoint POST /agreements: https://secure.na1.adobesign.com/public/docs/restapi/v6#!/agreements/createAgreement

The problem is, I want to use the same template to fill 2 documents (in a consequence, exist two fields with the same name), but when I merge the info I cant specify in which page the field is, so the default value is set in the two fields. How can I specify in which page the field is and fill each one with different information?

The petition I was using is:

```
{
  "fileInfos": [
    {
      "libraryDocumentId": templateId
    },
    {
      "libraryDocumentId": templateId
    }
  ],
  "name": "test",
  "participantSetsInfo": [
    {
      "order": 1,
      "role": "SIGNER",
       "name":"SIGNER1",
      "memberInfos": [
        {
          "email": signerEmail
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
"mergeFieldInfo": [
    {
      "defaultValue": "04/12/2022",
      "fieldName": "date"
    }
  ],
  "signatureType": "ESIGN",
  "state": "IN_PROCESS"
}
```

So, can I do something like?:

```
"mergeFieldInfo": [
    {
      "page":1
      "defaultValue": "04/12/2022",
      "fieldName": "date"
    },
    {
      "page":2
      "defaultValue": "06/03/2023",
      "fieldName": "date"
    }
  ]
```